# Plotting several filtered data on the same chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some doubts regarding plotting several data on the same chart, created by a function where the parameter is a well specified field.

```
def plot_freq(f):
    p=my_data.set_index('Date').Items.str.count(f).sum(level=0).to_frame('Count').reset_index()
    s2=p.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)
    ax=p.plot(x="Date", y=["Count"], kind="line", figsize=(30,20), legend=False)
    p.plot(ax=ax) 
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha='right')
    return(p)
```

This generates a plot by specifying the key search term `f`.

This means that if I have a sample of dataset

```
Date           Items
24/05/2020     Item_1
24/05/2020     Item_3
25/05/2020     Item_1
25/05/2020     Item_1
25/05/2020     Item_3
```

and so on

it will plot items through time as follows:

```
plot_freq('Item_1') for Item_1
plot_freq('Item_3') for Item_3
```

and so far.

I would like to compare the plots above on the same chart, but unfortunately in this way I have different plots.
In order to do this, I should have as many lines as Items.

Could you please tell me how to reach the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an axis object upfront and re-write `plot_freq()` to take a given axis as a keyword to be passed to `p.plot()`

```
def plot_freq(f,ax=None):

    p=my_data.set_index('Date').Items.str.count(f).sum(level=0).to_frame('Count').reset_index()

    s2=p.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)
    ax=p.plot(x="Date", y=["Count"], kind="line", figsize=(30,20), legend=False, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha='right')
    return(p)
```

Then create the axis and pass it as an argument to both calls.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plot_freq('Item_1', ax=ax)
plot_freq('Item_3', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Elliott Collins. May I ask you how to see the legends for each items? If I change legend there to True I get Counts as values for all the lines. Thanks

Comment: It's giving you 'Counts' because that's the name of the column in your data. You can rename that column to "f" inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

To work on the same figure (chart) you should create figure. I couldn't see plt.figure() After this you can get the current figure and do something on it. I think it will satisfy you.

plt.gcf() method (gcf corresponds to getcurrentfigure)